# How to detect Windows Startup

Tags: windows, restart

For a software i write, in my start operation i need to detect if it's my first run after the system restarted.
I Know that there has a Key that counts the restarts of the system:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters\BootId
```

but this key is not exist in Windows Server 2003.
There has a Key in the registry, WMI query or File-System object that i can check  for it?

byw - I don't want to use any "System Up Time" solution - I need it to be simple as much as it can.

Edit: I can use a System Up Time, but not from the WMI (because some servers can be with WMI Service disabled)

Comment: Does a suspend/resume count as a restart?

Comment: suspend/resume of what? do you mean Sleep mode of windows? if so, so no, i need to detect a windows start (startup from shutdown / restart)

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Why not install an idle service that is not launched by default, and launch it when you start your application?

Comment: it's good idea, but I don't want to take the chance that this service will be up all time.. I prefer to not depend on things that can be messed up